# ERROR: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try rewrite one application from MySQL to PostgreSQL.

In MySQL I have SQL statement:

```
SELECT u.guid, u.* 
FROM ossn_users as u 
WHERE(u.time_created IS NOT NULL) 
ORDER by u.guid ASC 
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

In Postgres I got for this statement error.
ERROR:  column u.guide must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

I modified SQL statment for PostgreSQL to this:

```
SELECT u.guid, u.* 
FROM ossn_users as u 
WHERE(u.time_created IS NOT NULL) 
GROUP by u.guid, u.type, u.username, u.email, u.password, 
         u.salt, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.last_login, 
         u.last_activity, u.activation, u.time_created 
ORDER by u.guid ASC 
LIMIT 0 OFFSET 10;
```

But in application it does not work.

Please help!

How I could modify MySQL statment to fit PostgrSQL needs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need a `GROUP BY`, I see no aggregate, but in postgresql, `LIMIT 0` will limit your results to 0.  Change your `LIMIT` and remove the `OFFSET` to get results from your postgresql query.

MySQL: `LIMIT 0, 10` means offset by 0, limit to 10

Postgresql: `LIMIT 10, OFFSET 0` or simply `LIMIT 10` means limit 10, offset by 0

Comment: Thanks.  I will try. And how it is in PostgreSQL when I need LIMIT from 30 to OFFSET 10 ? Thanks.

Comment: @floch That would be `LIMIT 30, OFFSET 10`